# How to slice numpy array to extract specific indices in a multidimentional array

Tags: python, numpy

- I have a Numpy array named `data` of shape `(300, 300, 300, 300)`
- I have a `bool` NumPy array named `mask` of shape `(300, 300)`

At runtime, values in the `mask` array are updated, and according to the indices of `True` entries in `mask`, I have to sum corresponding submatrices from `data`. The following code achieves the expected:

```
result = np.zeros((300, 300))
for i in range(300):
    for j in range(300):
        if mask[i, j]:
            result = result + data[i, j]
```

The above code is, however, very slow!

I am looking towards using NumPy's builtin slicing and indexing methods. Essentially the idea is as follows:

1. Use `np.where(mask==True)` to select the indices of `mask` that are `True`
2. Extract submatrix `reducedData` of shape `(M, N, 300, 300)` from `data` corresponding to the indices from *step 1*
3. Sum the `reducedData` array along axis 0, and axis 1 (`np.sum(reducedData, axis=(0, 1))`)

I'm not sure, how to achieve the **step 2** above. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is `np.sum(data[mask])` what you are looking for? It won't reduce the data to the dim you are describing but you'll get `(N, 300, 300)` out which should be sufficient for your task I guess.

Comment: @Ali_Sh I do not have familiarity with numba. Will it help me in speed up ? The current solution (suggested above) is causing MemoryError.

Comment: I have no idea why you got downvoted. This is a pretty textbook good question. You havea clear problem, an example and everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loops in the question can be accelerated by Numba based in the arrays sizes. So, if we can create an example as data:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(85)

number = 80
a = np.zeros((number//2, number), dtype=bool)
b = np.ones((number//2, number), dtype=bool)
con = np.concatenate((a, b)).ravel()
rng.shuffle(con)
mask = con.reshape(number, number)
Data = rng.random(number ** 4, dtype=np.float64).reshape(number, number, number, number)
result = np.zeros((number, number))
```

we can accelerate the code by parallelized `jitting` through Numba as:

```
@nb.njit("boolean[:,::1], float64[:,::1], float64[:,:,:,::1]", parallel=True)
def numba_(mask, result, Data):
    for i in nb.prange(number):
        for j in range(number):
            if (mask[i, j]):
                result = result + Data[i, j]
    return result
```

This was compared on my system in terms of performance. The code ran 3 to 4 times faster for smaller arrays and with array shape `(150,150,150,150)` it ran about 2 times faster. Larger arrays can not be tested due to memory leaks (memory issue was for Data creation by `rng.random` in my tests).
**To pass memory issues**, my [ex SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71824971/13394817) may be helpful. I tried to write some codes similar to the mentioned answer for this problem, but I couldn't complete this code after some time working on it (it was time-consuming to be debugged for me due to my workload) and it needs to be corrected if it needed. I put the incomplete code **JUST for inspiration how to use such *chunk*s**:

```
@nb.njit("boolean[:,::1], float64[:,::1], float64[:,:,:,::1]", parallel=True)
def numba_(mask, result, Data):
    chunk_val = 50                        # it is arbitrary and must be chosen based on the system rams size
    chunk = Data.shape[0] // chunk_val
    chunk_res = Data.shape[0] % chunk_val

    for i in range(chunk):
        for j in range(number):
            for k in range(i * chunk_val, (i + 1) * chunk_val):
                if mask[j, k]:
                    min_ind = i * chunk_val
                    max_ind = (i + 1) * chunk_val
                    result[:, min_ind:max_ind] = result[:, min_ind:max_ind] + Data[j, k][:, min_ind:max_ind]
            if i == chunk - 1:
                for k in range((i + 1) * chunk_val, Data.shape[0]):
                    if mask[j, k]:
                        result[:, -chunk_res:] = result[:, -chunk_res:] + Data[j, k][:, -chunk_res:]
    return result
```

Note that this code must be evaluated in terms of memory consumption after the completion, but will be as my proposed answer using numba in terms of speed.

### Benchmarks (core i5 G.no1, Ram 16):

```
shape = (70, 70, 70, 70)               (~x3 _ very faster)
31247600    ns    --> OP code
0           ns    --> Numba accelerated

shape = (100, 100, 100, 100)           (~x2.5)
78147400    ns    --> OP code
31229900    ns    --> Numba accelerated

shape = (150, 150, 150, 150)           (~x2)
390626400   ns    --> OP code
218730800   ns    --> Numba accelerated

shape = (170, 170, 170, 170)           (~x2)
625012500   ns    --> OP code
328132000   ns    --> Numba accelerated
```

- **Updated benchmarks on [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SYWjTdEwbtw4q-oQ5VxfxWsVHRIpfnv2?usp=sharing)** (*comparing to [Mad Physicist solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71851691/13394817)*)

```
10 loops, best of 5: 46.4 ms per loop    # This answer (numba)   (~x7)
10 loops, best of 5: 344  ms per loop    # Mad Physicist
```

Comment: But why not just use indexing?

Comment: Could you benchmark against `np.add.reduceat`? I posted an answer.

Comment: Also, what's with 0ns?

Comment: The second number is 0. That's better than 3x faster...

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I used `time.time_ns()` to evaluate these and copied pasted the results here; it get `0 ns` almost always for that data volume (in small data volumes this comparison may be tolerance a lot). Often, the result was `>x3` for this small data volume; it was at least ~x3 in the worst run. I did not have time to evaluate your code. I will do it now.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I have tested your solution with numba [on colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SYWjTdEwbtw4q-oQ5VxfxWsVHRIpfnv2?usp=sharing), and numba was much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Over trick is to use `np.add.reduceat` to avoid creating a giant temporary array. For example, on my machine, summing a `(300, 300, 100, 100)` array (which is the largest I'm able to allocate) takes less than a second this way:

```
np.add.reduce(data, axis=(0, 1), out=out, where=mask[..., None, None])
```

The only caveat is that you don't have the luxury of broadcasting the mask: you have to explicitly set the dimensions.

As it happens, your loop is not so slow: it runs ~2x faster than the vectorized operation on my machine.

```
np.random.seed(435)
data = np.random.uniform(size=(300, 300, 100, 100))
mask = np.random.randint(2, size=(300, 300), dtype=bool)
out = np.zeros((100, 100), float)

result = np.zeros((100, 100))
for i in range(300):
    for j in range(300):
        if mask[i, j]:
            result = result + data[i, j]

(result == out).all() ## True
```

```
%timeit np.add.reduce(data, axis=(0, 1), out=out, where=mask[..., None, None])
715 ms ± 1.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
result = np.zeros((100, 100))
for i in range(300):
    for j in range(300):
        if mask[i, j]:
            result = result + data[i, j]
442 ms ± 2.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Either of these methods has a huge advantage over what you are proposing, in that they do not use a large amount of memory. Your three steps boil down to

```
data[mask].sum(0)
```

You can skip step 1, since numpy allows indexing with a boolean mask, and a mask can only produce a 1D output, since the rows may contain different numbers of elements, hence the single sum. The issue is that `data[mask]` simply kills my interpreter because the temporary array size is too large.

Comment: "As it happens, your loop is not so slow: it runs ~2x faster than the vectorized operation.."   Indeed, I verified this at my end. I had this impression that numpy inbuilt functions do things faster. So, for the time being, I'm going to use the loopy version and will also try to figure out how to use `numba` to further speed up the computations as user @Ali_Sh has suggested.

Comment: @vyi. You should select Ali's excellent answer